# Flask on VPS redirects to 127.0.0.1 instead of the VPS' IP address

Tags: python

I am currently working on a small program for my school and ran into a small problem with my flask program. Basically, I put my program on my ec2 VPS and whenever I use return #DO SOMETHING it will go to 127.0.0.1/webpage instead of the VPS' IP Address, this only happens when the program is running on the vps. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

The following code is the code I am using to run the flask program.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run on the VPS IP address. In production, you must use a production-ready web server. Like, Nginx, Apache, etc. Learn how to deploy flask app on VPS.

Here is an example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps